# Android service does not restart once it is killed by clearing application from recent apps or OS kill it

Tags: android, android-service

I'm facing strange issue with Android service. I'm creating a application locker which has a service which will keep checking which application is in foreground and take necessary action accordingly. All working fine as long as service is running. Once I clear application from recent application or application or service is killed by Android OS on low memory it never starts.

**What I have did to resolve issue:**

1. Try to restart service on `onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent)` and `onDestroy()`
2. Used pending intent and alarm manager to restart service
3. Running service as a different process name e.g `android:name=".view.locker.CheckAppService"`
4. Disabled stopwith task in manifest e.g `android:stopWithTask="false"`

Nothing seems to work. Please help.

For your reference I'm sharing entire service code below:

```
public class CheckAppService extends Service{private static Timer timer = new Timer();public Boolean userAuth = false;private Context ctx;public String pActivity="";private String lastPackageName = "";


public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
{
    return null;
}

public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    ctx = this;
    startService();
    Utility.printLog("@@@@ service started");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

private void startService()
{
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new mainTask(), 0, 500);
}

private class mainTask extends TimerTask
{
    public void run()
    {
        toastHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    Utility.printLog("@@@@ service destroyed");

    Intent intent = new Intent("com.e2e.mobicleaner.locker.restart");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    /*Intent intent = new Intent("com.e2e.mobicleaner.locker.restart");
    sendBroadcast(intent);*/

    Intent restartServiceTask = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),this.getClass());
    restartServiceTask.setPackage(getPackageName());
    PendingIntent restartPendingIntent =PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1,restartServiceTask, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager myAlarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    myAlarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000, restartPendingIntent);
}

private final Handler toastHandler = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        String currentPackage = null;
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            UsageStatsManager mUsageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager)getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            // We get usage stats for the last 10 seconds
            List<UsageStats> stats = mUsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, time - 1000*1, time);
            // Sort the stats by the last time used
            if(stats != null) {
                SortedMap<Long,UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<Long,UsageStats>();
                for (UsageStats usageStats : stats) {
                    mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(),usageStats);
                }
                if(!mySortedMap.isEmpty()) {
                    currentPackage =  mySortedMap.get(mySortedMap.lastKey()).getPackageName();
                }
            }

            Utility.printLog("@@@@ currentPackage: " + currentPackage);
            Utility.printLog("@@@@ lastPackage: " + lastPackageName);
        }
        else {
            ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningTask = mActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

            //
        /*for (ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo aTask : RunningTask) {

            System.out.println("###########");
            System.out.println("@@@@@@ running base: "+aTask.baseActivity.flattenToShortString());
            System.out.println("@@@@@@ running base: "+aTask.baseActivity.getClassName());
            System.out.println("@@@@@@ running: "+aTask.topActivity.flattenToShortString());
            System.out.println("@@@@@@ running: "+aTask.topActivity.getClassName());
            System.out.println("##########");


        }*/

            currentPackage = runningTask.get(0).processName;

            Utility.printLog("@@@@ currentPackage: " + currentPackage);
            Utility.printLog("@@@@ lastPackage: " + lastPackageName);
        }

        SharedPreferences spLockedApps = CheckAppService.this.getSharedPreferences("lockedApp", Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
        SharedPreferences spUnLockedApps = CheckAppService.this.getSharedPreferences("unLockedApp", Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
        Utility.printLog("@@@@ LockedApp count: "+spLockedApps.getAll().size());
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(currentPackage) && !currentPackage.equalsIgnoreCase(getPackageName())) {
            if (spUnLockedApps.contains(currentPackage)) {

            } else if (spLockedApps.contains(currentPackage) && !currentPackage.equalsIgnoreCase(lastPackageName)) {
                Utility.printLog("@@@@ else else");

                Intent intent = new Intent(CheckAppService.this, LockActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(Lock.TYPE, Lock.UNLOCK_APP);
                intent.putExtra(Lock.MESSAGE, getString(R.string.enter_passcode));
                intent.putExtra(Lock.PACKAGE_NAME, currentPackage);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

            lastPackageName = currentPackage;
        }
    }
};
```

}

Manifest declaring of service

```
<service
        android:name=".view.locker.CheckAppService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:process="com.e2e.mobicleaner.view.locker.service"
        android:stopWithTask="false" />
```

Comment: What device are you using? And what version of Anroid OS is it running?

Comment: @DavidWasser, I'm using Samsung, Panasonic Lollipop and marshmallow device.

Comment: Please remove the `"android:process"` attribute from your `<service>` tag and see if this helps.

Comment: @DavidWasser, thanks sir, I'll check it.

Comment: And??? Did it help?